# When I type "www..." in Chrome's URL bar, what makes Chrome decide that it should use HTTP or HTTPS for that site?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

The subject line pretty much says it all.  When you enter a website URL *without* an HTTP/HTTPS prefix in the URL bar, I thought Chrome would always prefer HTTPS, or use history/bookmarks as a guide to decide which to use.

However, I have a site (and older, mediawiki-using site) with both HTTP and HTTPS versions, and Chrome always chooses HTTP for it, despite me deleting all HTTP history entries and bookmarks, and having many history entries/bookmarks for HTTPS URLs on that site.

So clearly there is *something* about that site that makes Chrome choose HTTP: can anyone explain how Chrome makes this decision?

Comment: If you type http://www.somesite.com  the site will normally choose https if need be. Most sites are https now anyway

Comment: In general yes, but again under some circumstances Chrome does not automatically choose HTTPS, even when the site offers it.  So that's what I'm trying to understand: how does Chome decide (so I can understand why it decides to pick HTTP in this site's case)?

Comment: Let me try this way:  I see the same thing in several operating systems in Chrome, IE, Firefox and (when I rarely us it) Internet Explorer for routers.

Comment: Right, you see the same thing ... *on the sites you're visiting*.  We're mostly in violent agreement with each other: we both agree that on *most* sites, if you just type "www..." Chrome will autocomplete to HTTPS.  But the critical detail, and the reason I'm here asking the question, is the fact that on *some* sites, Chrome *does not* autocomplete to HTTPS: it completes with HTTP.  I'm trying to understand why/under what circumstances it does that, so telling me what Chrome does in the other cases, even if they're the majority, doesn't answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: "on some sites, ..."    I am fairly sure that is by site control so users do not have to think about it. Some of my "sites" are routers and there is no autocomplete / autochange. I just have to do it correctly. So for most people the site does the work (not the browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default has always been HTTP in the past – and the default is still HTTP today, *unless* the browser remembers that the domain has an [HSTS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) policy which enforces HTTPS for all requests (even if you manually enter http://).

(Chrome contains a list of "preloaded" HSTS domains, which always use HTTPS without exceptions. Other domains can dynamically opt in by sending a special [Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) header – the first time you visit such a site via HTTPS, the browser locks it into HSTS mode.)

Additionally, many websites serve an HTTP version that just always redirects visitors to HTTPS using a [301 'Moved Permanently'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) or another similar redirect code. Even if there's no HSTS set up, "permanent" redirects would be stored in the browser's cache and that can also cause requests to directly go to the 'new' URL (although this is per-page, not per-domain).

Both methods result in the URL bar *eventually* containing an "https://" address, although behind the scenes they work differently – HSTS policy is applied locally (no plaintext requests ever happen) while redirects are applied by the server (and vulnerable to being spoofed). Most websites combine both methods.

Comment: "Other domains can dynamically opt in by sending a special header" - Can you provide any details about this header?  Even just its name alone would be helpful.

Comment: I've linked to an article about it. The header is [Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security).

Comment: As of Chrome 90 the default has been changed to https.
https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html

Answer (score 0):

Apache or Nginx configurations tell the browser if they should be using http or https.

Edit: Specifically, Apache and Nginx Virtual Hosts dictate whether a domain is going to have an SSL or not. If you open a browser and view the network tab in Chrome when you load a website via http for the first time you will often see that the first request is commonly a 301 redirect if the domain has an SSL.

The browser uses the domain name to connect to the server through distributed DNS servers. Once the request hits the host server, Apache or Nginx config files directives are loaded. The domain is then compared to the virtual hosts in the config and if the domain matches one, the directives tell the browser which port to use. Port 443 is https and 80 is http, generally.

Heres what the VirtualHosts look like (Apache) and how its setup on the host server:

https://serverfault.com/questions/744960/configuring-ssl-with-virtual-hosts-under-apache-and-centos

(Ignore the question and look at the accepted answer)

Edit 2: Something else I forgot. Having both https and http virtualhosts do not automatically force redirects. Websites  can load through both. Redirects are generally setup through `.htaccess` rules in apache or directives in nginx which force the redirects, depending on the admins preferences. So my comment below is somewhat wrong.

Comment: Could you clarify?  Do you mean (for instance) that there's a specific HTTP header the server returns which indicates "use HTTP instead of HTTPS", and if so what header would that be?

Comment: Edited my response

Comment: Ah, so the setting tells the server to send a redirect (not a response with a specific header)?

Comment: Yes and no. The virtualhosts are used to tell the browser if it needs to redirect or not using the `Location` HTTP header.

Comment: Updated my answer again. My last comment is somewhat incorrect since redirects are not always enforced through the VirtualHosts. Some people want to offer the choice of http and https, for instance.